# get file names to NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have images in Images folder, and i would like to initialize an array with strings of file name...

ex:

one.png, two.png, three.png

I would like to initialize my array as ["one", "two", "three"]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Retrieve an array of paths in the given directory
NSArray *imagePaths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: @"/Images/" error: NULL];

if(imagePaths==nil || [imagePaths count]==0) {
    //Path either does not exist or does not contain any files
    return;
}

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [imagePaths objectEnumerator];
id imagePath;
NSString *newImageName;

NSMutableArray *imageNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while (imagePath = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    //Remove the file extension
    newImageName = [imagePath stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    [imageNames addObject:newImageName];
}
```

The first part of the code retrieves the names of the files in the given directory, and adds them to the `imagePaths` array.

The second part of the code then loops over the image paths in the array and removes the extension from the end (using the `stringByDeletingPathExtension` method), appending them to the `imageNames` array, which will contain all the files in the given directory without any file extensions.

As `Graham Lee` has done in his code, you could provide a pointer to an `NSError` object to obtain information about the problem, should an error arise.

Comment: This, in my limited experience, is one million times nicer than keeping track of a .plist.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *imageFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: @"/path/to/Images/" error: &error];
if (imageFiles == nil) //handle the error
```